# While implementing Facebook audience network ads (interstitial) ,getting this java.lang.IllegalStateException: ad already started

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

**App gets crashed due to facebook audience network ads (interstitial)**
 Earlier it was working fine in another app, now this problem
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: ad already started**

Error shows :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ad already started
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.show(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.arham.csdevbin.healthybody.mFragment.DietFragment$5.onAdLoaded(DietFragment.java:221)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd$1.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$11.onInterstitialAdLoaded(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.l$2.c(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.l$2.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.facebook.ads.internal.c.b$1$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

and here is the code for ads........

```
 public void loadInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(getActivity(), "962300780587295_962314293919277");
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
           interstitialAd.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
        }
    });
    interstitialAd.loadAd();
}
```

I do not know why this error is coming.

**Added**

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diet, container, false);


 loadInterstitialAd();

    return view;
```

}

Comment: are you calling this method `loadInterstitialAd()` twice? for the same ad?

Comment: no, it called just once in the onCreate method.

Comment: nope i am talking about you , have you called the method twice?

Comment: once in Oncreate method

Comment: can you post your onCreate code here

Comment: added in edit @AbdulKawee

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.So I reported the error to Facebook and they told to me to upgrade the Facebook Audience Network SDK to

> com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1

Now its working fine without any exception.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    loadInterstitialAd();
 }
```

override another method `onViewCreated()`